# How to fix this particular "The call is ambiguous ..."

Tags: c#, .net

I usually know how to fix these, but this one I don't know how to make unambiguous.

I have

```
new InArgument<IEnumerable<Foo>>(new List<Foo>() { foo })
```

and the compiler says

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'InArgument.InArgument(T)' and
>   'InArgument.InArgument(Activity)'

The one I want is `InArgument<T>.InArgument(T)`.

How can I disambiguate?

Comment: Is this is web api method??

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show some more relevant code. from what you've shared, seems like these are constructors. We also don't know what `Activity` is, so it's kinda hard to tell.

Comment: `Activity` is from `System.Activities`

Comment: For everyone's reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465965(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you share sources of the `InArgument` class? Or at least its constructors?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your list new to `IEnumerable<Foo>`

```
new InArgument<IEnumerable<Foo>>((IEnumerable<Foo>)new List<Foo>() { foo })
```

You are getting this problem because `Activity` has implicit operators to turn any type into an `Activity`, this means your list could just as easily be `IEnumerable` or an `Activity`.